# What is the best way to let access to physical files in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file, routes

I did not find which is the best following to serve physical files to the users in a MVC3 app.
For example if I want to put my site in search engines, they ask me to place an xml file in the site root.
This file can not be accessed because I think the routing does not "catch" the url...

Thanks¡¡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to ignore route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("/filename.xml");
```

Or:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("filename.xml");
```

And that should be done in `Global.asax` file and `RegisterRoutes()` function

Answer (score 1):

did you try opening the file through your web browser?
if you tried and it didn't open then you can do the following
in global.asax
write the following
    C#
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{*xml}", new { xml = @"(.*)?abc.xml" }); where abc is the file name or you can but * instead of abc to ignore all xml files

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the permissions on the file system with a chmod (700) or equivalent. Usually this is where the protections come in.